# Setting a minimum width to viewport in GXT

Tags: gwt, viewport, gxt

Is there a way i can set a minimum width to the Viewport? The Viewport should work as usual beyond this width.. Im using GXT 2.2.5 and GWT 2.4 in the  project.

Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just as usual: Set something like

```
body {
  min-width: 1000px;
}
```

in your CSS file.

If you're using RootLayoutPanel or something else that's positioned absolutely, then set the min-width on that container, e.g.

```
// Java:

  RootLayoutPanel.get().addStyleName("requires-min-width");

// CSS:

  .requires-min-width {
    min-width: 1000px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First sentence of the class level javadoc taken directly from GXT 2.2.5 source code;

> A LayoutContainer that fills the browser window and monitors window resizing.

So, you shouldn't have to set a minimum width. It will fill the browser window. Then, if the browser window resizes, it should resize with it.

Comment: I think the question is saying 'if the browser window is too small, how can one ask the Viewport to show a scrollbar so the app still can function'.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself. GWT 2.8 and GXT 4.0.1

Extend the Viewport class and overwrite the onWindowResize and doLayout method as follows

```
         Viewport viewport = new Viewport() {

            @Override
            protected void onWindowResize(int width, int height) {
                int minWidthChecked = Math.max(width, MIN_WIDTH);
                int minHeightChecked = Math.max(height, MIN_HEIGHT);

                super.onWindowResize(minWidthChecked, minHeightChecked);
            }

            @Override
            protected void doLayout() {
                Size size = getContainerTarget().getStyleSize();
                size.setWidth(Math.max(size.getWidth(), MIN_WIDTH));
                size.setHeight(Math.max(size.getHeight(), MIN_HEIGHT));
                getContainerTarget().setSize(size);

                super.doLayout();
            }

        };
```

This way all the children of the viewport which implement RequiresResize will get the proper width and height. The override of doLayout is necessary to correct the size on initial load if the page is smaller than the mins.

Finally make sure the following styles are applied

```
html {
   overflow: auto !Important;
}

body {
   min-width: 1024px;
   min-height: 800px;
}
```

For some reason I think GWT adds the overflow hidden to the html. Another good idea would be to reference the values of MIN_WIDTH and MIN_HEIGHT using the @eval construct of GSS that way it is defined in one place.